# Bulding a new "Core Data" AtomicStore, the missing pieces

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am in the process to implement an AtomicStore subclass to save data in a MySQL DB. The system already works pretty well besides the implementation of fetch-requests.
The fetches should include the cached nodes but also fire a "select" on the underlaying SQL db.

I have currently only worked on SubClasses for NSAtomicStore and NSAtomicStoreCacheNode. So running a fetch will only result to search within any cached nodes. 
As fetched is effectively done on an NSManagedObjectContext instance I would assume that also this class needs an overwrite.

Anyway in my current understanding of Core Data I assumed that anything specific for a "custom store" will be done only in NSAtomicStore (and NSAtomicStoreCacheNode). So I looked for something here will should execute a fetch.

As the SQLite implementation is not avail. in source code I digged a bit into "GnuStep", here a "fetch-method" is injected into the NSAtomicStore. Maybe somebody can point me to the right direction here.

Thus maybe there are some "hidden" interfaces on NSAtomicStore to be overridden or the need to subclass NSManagedObjectContext.

Comment: Bear in mind you're rather out on a limb here as MySQL is not an atomic store.

Comment: An atomic store is supposed to load the entire store into memory at once. If you can do this you probably don’t want or need to use a SQL database. For this you’d have to create a subclass of `NSPersistentStore` which the documentation says isn’t supported.

Answer (score 3):

This question couldn't really be solved when it was written in 2010, but the "missing link" for solving this problem was provided in Mac OS X 10.7 and iOS 5 in the form of the [`NSIncrementalStore`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010706) abstract class. `NSIncrementalStore` subclasses can be implemented that hook up to MySQL, other RDBMS, "NoSQL" databases, or even [web services](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore).